# Cant access Android Crouton Library when using Gradle?

Tags: android, import, gradle, build.gradle, crouton

I am currently starting to develop a new Android application and I am having a strange problem when trying to import a Library using the new Gradle build system. I have added everything I need to the **build.gradle** file (*as shown below*) but when i try to access the Crouton functionality or import the namespace it cant find it and im not sure why:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "18.1.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 18
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile ('de.keyboardsurfer.android.widget:crouton:1.8.1') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+'
    }
}
```

The library in question is below and when I go to my Activity and start typing "**de.keyboardsur...**" into the import section it cant find the reference to import. I am sure I am just missing something sill as im new to Gradle maybe but I would appreciate some help.

https://github.com/keyboardsurfer/Crouton

Thanks in advance

---

************EDIT**********************

---

Fixed the issue as it appears my Android Studio got stuck and had to force quit it and was all good on restart.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Crouton Library java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19845589/android-crouton-library-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror)

Comment: You should remove : compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar').
Simply you can use:
    // Support Libraries
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0' //or 19
    //Crouton
    compile ('de.keyboardsurfer.android.widget:crouton:1.8.1') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }