# Android Crouton Library java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError?

Tags: android, android-studio, noclassdeffounderror, crouton

I am currently starting to develop a new Android application using Android Studio. I have updated the Gradle build file and I have successfully added the Crouton Library. I have a Drawer Navigation setup and when I click on an item I want to test the Crouton by displaying it so I used the code below:

```
@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
     Crouton.makeText(this, "Test", Style.ALERT).show();
}
```

When I run this code it builds fine but the app crashes and I get the stack trace below:

```
11-07 19:49:10.474    1212-1212/com.oss.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: de.keyboardsurfer.android.widget.crouton.Style
            at com.oss.app.HomeActivity.onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(HomeActivity.java:59)
            at com.oss.app.NavigationDrawerFragment.selectItem(NavigationDrawerFragment.java:204)
            at com.oss.app.NavigationDrawerFragment.onCreate(NavigationDrawerFragment.java:79)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1477)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:893)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1082)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1184)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:291)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:676)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:256)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superSetContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:216)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:111)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:76)
            at com.oss.app.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:40)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I understand that the issue is to do with the Style class not being found at run-time but I have added it as an import on the page so I don't know what could be causing this. I would really appreciate some help on this.

Thanks in advance

---

Edit

---

My **build.gradle** file is below:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "18.1.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 18
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
    compile files('libs/com.haarman.listviewanimations-2.5.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile ('de.keyboardsurfer.android.widget:crouton:1.8.1') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+'
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post your build.gradle file?

Answer (score 1):

I often run into the same problem when adding libraries in Android Studio via Gradle. What works for me is to run "gradlew.bat clean assembleDebug" from the console inside your project's folder.

Comment: I tried to run that from within Android Studio terminal and got this: 'gradlew.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: @user723858, Try it from the system command line, it should work.